# How can I pass a value from a drop down list to another page in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to have a page where an option is selected from a drop down list that is passed to the next page. The error I receive is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currentuser' referenced before assignment". I'm not sure how to update the variable globally when an option is selected from the drop down list or how to access the global variable locally in the next page function. I am new to python and flask, any help would be greatly appreciated!

*app.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/selectusername')
def selectusername_page():
    # connect to database and populate userlist
    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    userlist = c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('selectusername.html', userlist=userlist)

@app.route('/showusername')
def showusername_page():
    currentuser=currentuser
    return render_template('showusername.html', currentuser=currentuser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*selectusername.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
    <button onclick="window.location.href = 'showusername';">Continue</button>
        <h1>Select User</h1>
<select id="currentuser">
{% for user in userlist %}
  <option value="{{user[0]}}">{{user[0]}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

*showusername.html*

```
<h1>Hello {{ currentuser }}</h1>
```

Comment: You should use a `<form>` in your web page.

Comment: I am not familiar with <form>, adding it around the <select> section did not seem to change anything. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Using forms is one of the most important concepts of web development. You should find out how to use them and how to use the submitted data in Django. There are countless resources on HTML forms on the internet.

Comment: I use Flask rather than Django but I'm pretty sure the concept is the same. Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: If you use JavaScript to change page then you should use JavaScript to get selected value and add to url like `showusername?currentuser=value` and then you should get it  in function `showusername` using `requests.args.get("currentuser")`

Comment: if you use `<form>` and button without `JavaScript` then you can get selected value in `showusername` using `request.form.get("currentuser")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
<form action="/showusername">
```

and button without `JavaScript` and you use `name="currentuser"` in `<select>`

```
<select name="currentuser">
```

then it can send selected value in url

```
/showusername?currentuser=selected_name
```

and you can get it in `showusername` using `request.args`

```
currentuser = request.args.get("currentuser")
```

---

To hide name from url you would have to use `POST` method - so you have to set

```
<form action="/showusername" method="POST">
```

and in flask

```
@app.route('/showusername', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

and then you get it using `request.form` instead of `request.args`

```
currentuser = request.form.get("currentuser")
```

---

Full running example

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string, request

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/selectusername')
def selectusername_page():

    userlist = [['James'], ['Adam'], ['Mark']]

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<form action="/showusername">
    <button>Continue</button>
        <h1>Select User</h1>
<select id="currentuser" name="currentuser">
{% for user in userlist %}
  <option value="{{user[0]}}">{{user[0]}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>''', userlist=userlist)

@app.route('/showusername', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def showusername_page():
    print('args:', request.args)
    print('form:', request.form)

    #currentuser = request.args.get("currentuser")
    currentuser = request.form.get("currentuser")

    return render_template_string('''<h1>Hello {{ currentuser }}</h1>''', currentuser=currentuser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

If you want to use `JavaScript` in button then you would have to use `JavaScript` to get selected value and add it to url like

```
 window.location.href = 'showusername?currentuser=selected_name'
```

so it is more complicated and I don't put code in `JavaScript`. Maybe someone else will show this.