# Python check radio button is True or False

Tags: python, html, flask, radio-button

I have a database of multiple-choice questions (4 choices) with correct keys. I put 10 of them on a page.

Now I want to check if each of them is True or False when I click "Submit" button. How can I do that?

My code is here:

```
{% block content %}
{% set i = namespace(value=1) %}
{% for question in questions.items %} 
<form action="{{ url_for('result') }}" method="POST">
    <article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="article-metadata">[{{ question.question_id }}] Câu {{ i.value }}</h5> <br>
            <p class="article-content">{{ question.content }}</p>

            <br>
            <div style="width: 50%;float: left;max-width: 50%; word-wrap: break-word;;">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="A"> A. {{ question.key_A }}</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="B"> B. {{ question.key_B }}</label>
            </div>

            <div style="width: 50%;float: left; max-width: 50%; word-wrap: break-word;">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="C"> C. {{ question.key_C }}</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="D"> D. {{ question.key_D }}</label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </article>
    {% set i.value = i.value +1 %}
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Done!"
                style="margin-bottom: 15%;width: 25%;">Done!</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: check `request.form` in `Flask` view/function

Comment: Could you explain more? I'm still confused about your idea!

Comment: it is not idea - it is standard method to work with any form. Browser sends form data to server and Flask on server get it in `request.form` - you should see it in any tutorial.

Comment: BTW: where do you have tag `<form action="some_url" method="POST">` ?

Comment: I dont have that ```<form>``` right now. Should I use it to wrap the submit?

Comment: without `<form>` button will not work and it will not send data to server. In `action="url"`  you show which function has to get these data from form.

Comment: I have even 10 questions. Where should I put ```request.form``` in my code?

Comment: if you use `action="some_url"` then put in function assigned to `"some_url"`. And first try `print( request.form )` to see what you get. Later you can use ie. `request.form.get("optradio")` to get result for one question. Every question should have own `name` ie `name="optradio-1"`, `name="optradio-2"`, etc.

Comment: I put ```<form action="{{ url_for('result') }}" method="POST">``` in my code. But when i open result page, i got  ```<bound method MultiDict.items of ImmutableMultiDict([])>```

Comment: did you add `<form...>` before all widgets - `<input>`, `<button>`, `<select>`, etc. ? Did you add closing tag  `</form>` after all widgets?

Comment: yesterday I put code for similar question [How can I pass a value from a drop down list to another page in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59341800/1832058)

Comment: Actually, I fixed the problem I had asked! But now I've got another problem =))
I have 10 multiple-choice question but I just can choose ONE choice of all 10 questions. I think that I put some <div> in wrong places.

Comment: I said it before - every question should have own name ie `name="optradio-1"`, `name="optradio-2"`, etc. - and then you will have 10 variabels so you will have 10 answers.

Comment: If I change "optradio" to "optradio-1",... then do I need to change ```request.form.get("otpradio")``` and change to what?

Comment: `request.form.get("otpradio-1")`, `request.form.get("otpradio-2")`, ... `request.form.get("otpradio-10")`

Comment: I have a ```def task()``` and that's where I put my Questions into the file .html above. I want to show number of correct questions that I have chosen. I have tried using ```if request.method=='POST'``` in my def task() and ```<form action=" {{url_for('task')}}>``` but then I get infinity loop in the task page when I click submit. What should I do now?

Comment: It is strange. Maybe create new question on new page and you will have more space to put code and description. And new people will see it so you may get more answers/solutions.